# How to add 'audience' in body for OAuth2 token fetch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to access an OAuth protected resource and before that I have to fetch a token.
I am using a feign client and configuring the client details using **ClientCredentialsResourceDetails**.
Now the documentation says that I can fetch the token by sending these details in the POST request body.

```
{
    "client_id": "client_id",
    "client_secret": "client_secret",
    "audience": "https://soma-api.com/a/status",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
```

and all the fields in the body are required.

Everything seems to be fine but I am unable to find the **audience** configuration option with **ClientCredentialsResourceDetails**

```
final ClientCredentialsResourceDetails details = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
details.setAccessTokenUri("https://some-server.com/oauth/token");
details.setClientId("client_id");
details.setClientSecret("secret_id");
return details;
```

I have followed [this](https://github.com/netshoes/sample-feign-oauth2-interceptor) tutorial

Here are the links for my [Config](https://github.com/netshoes/sample-feign-oauth2-interceptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sample/feign/oauth2/interceptor/OrderFeignClientConfiguration.java) and [FeignClient](https://github.com/netshoes/sample-feign-oauth2-interceptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sample/feign/oauth2/interceptor/OrderFeignClient.java)

How can I add 'audience' to the body to fetch the token?

Comment: well its impossible to provide any suggestion as to how you should be able to add "audience" to your implementation since you have not posted any code that shows your client, and what your client implementation looks like. All you have written is "I am using a feign client" and that tells us nothing.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Thanks for your reply. I was not sure whether those details were required. I have added the links for the tutorial I have followed and the sample code as well.